# Connection to HTTPS server offline with a PWA

Tags: https, server, ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps, offline

currently I am working on PWA (progressive web app) that needs fully functional offline capabilities. Currently the client is hosted on Heroku and is fully functional offline, besides one key feature. The PWA is not able to connect to the local server I am running from a separate computer. I made a self-signed cert so the localhost server computer is able to connect to it's running server via HTTPS; but I am unable to connect a different computer on the LAN to the same server. I'm fairly new to certificates and how they work, and I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: for localhost you do not need HTTPS

Comment: If your using a PWA yes you do, because the it's still an HTTPS website even when offline.

Comment: no you do not. I have been developing PWAs since 2014. http://localhost works. It is written into the service worker specification.
Plus if you are offline there is no network traffic, you run from local cache, so nothing to encrypt. 
It was written into the specification so developers would not need to fuss with installing TLS certificates on their dev machines.

Comment: Well if I run the client as localhost yes it works fine, I'm talking about the online client connecting to local server. If I'm wrong then I'm happy to hear. I'm just not sure how to fix it because my websockets try and use WSS rather than WS; but when I run the client local they use WS.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to make a server endpoint where I could accept the certificate. This was weird initially because the application is a SPA. So currently the user would have to differ for the initial setup.